# Link errors building a visual studio Qt project linking to a library buillt using QT

Tags: c++, qt, linker, visual-c++-2010

I have a library that uses QT. The library was staticly linked with QT. I am now using this library in another application (exe) that also uses QT. The problem I am having is when I compile I receive a large number of Linker re-definition errors.

My assumption was that by static linking the QT libs in my library I would avoid this.

How can keep these methods from being exported. Is a def File the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue, the problem had nothing to do with the static libs. The problem was (which I still haven't solved) when I make an edit cpp files that have the Qobject macro the moc_ file property exclude from build is set resulting in link errors